# Are there any filler episodes in Kaguya-sama:Love Is War?

Tags: kaguya-sama-love-is-war

Which episodes in the anime are filler (if there are any)?

Comment: What do you mean by filler? Many of the episodes are stand-alone and especially in Season 1 there isn't much of a running narrative. Do you mean episodes that didn't come from the manga?

Comment: If you mean non-manga, then it would have to be very few, if any. I actually remember reading chapters in the manga that weren't adapted.

Comment: The whole show is a slice of life kinda comedy. What do you mean? It's like asking what filler episodes are there in Lucky Star I think

Comment: Now that I've seen both seasons I think in some ways this could be a good question. Some episodes esp in season 1 seem to be standalone things that are merely 'filler' but then they are referenced in future episodes.

Comment: @ConMan See my answer. They might seem like filler but are referenced later on. Do you disagree with Shaymin Gratitude?

Comment: @ShayminGratitude See my answer. Depending on how you define the term filler, it can indeed have very few or it can have a lot. Do you disagree with ConMan?

Comment: It's still a very vague thing, especially if there is no clear information on the author's intent and whether any of the apparent throwaway gags or random characters were designed to be returned to. And even so, does it count if one of the appearances can be removed without affecting the other? You could claim the final scene in S2 is filler, since the opening of S3 actively retcons it to the point where from the characters' POV it never even happened, but there could still be a side gag where someone mentions oranges or balloons and another character reacts.

Comment: @ConMan I don't disagree with you. That's why I gave more than 1 answer. It depends on how 'filler' is defined. In the usual sense, of course Kaguya-sama has filler. For me, I think the show invites you to redefine 'filler'.

Answer (score 1):

I have 2 answers to this:

## Answer 1

Check out the [story arcs](https://kaguyasama-wa-kokurasetai.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Story_Arcs) and then I guess the chapters that aren't part of story arcs are fillers. Then the corresponding parts in the anime are fillers.

## Answer 2

I said initially in March

> The whole show is a slice of life kinda comedy. What do you mean? It's like asking what filler episodes are there in Lucky Star I think –
> BCLC

And then I said just before Easter

> Now that I've seen both seasons I think in some ways this could be a good question. Some episodes esp in s1 seem to be standalone things that are merely 'filler' but then they are referenced in future episodes. –
> BCLC

The question I would instead ask is 'Are there *really* any filler episodes?' For example, you might consider the following fillers, but they're kinda referenced in later chapters/episodes

1. [Chapter 43: Chika Fujiwara Really Wants to Eat](https://kaguyasama-wa-kokurasetai.fandom.com/wiki/Chapter_43), part of [S01E11](https://kaguyasama-wa-kokurasetai.fandom.com/wiki/Episode_11).
2. [Chapter 9: Kaguya Wants to Walk](https://kaguyasama-wa-kokurasetai.fandom.com/wiki/Chapter_9), part of [S01E03](https://kaguyasama-wa-kokurasetai.fandom.com/wiki/Episode_03).

But each are relevant, at least a little, in later episodes (again, s1 spoilers)

1. For S01E11, (s1 minor spoiler)

> We see the ramen guy as a taxi driver in S01E12.

2. For S01E03, we can view this as relevant to (s1 spoiler)

> The umbrella episode S01E05 (re Miyuki's bike riding to school) and the non-meeting at the student council room in S01E11 (The interpretation seems to be that for S01E03 Kaguya and Miyuki meet up serendipitously when they do good things like help out children, but for S01E11 they don't meet up serendipitously when they do bad things like hiding their feelings).

My view is that **Kaguya-sama invites you to redefine your definition of 'filler'** to something like: 'an episode/a sub-episode/a chapter that (isn't an end in and of itself and) isn't referenced in future episodes/chapters'. One might also add that Miyuki vs Kaguya battles are ends in and of themselves, so for example the umbrella sub-episode of S01E05 isn't filler because the point of the show is really to show these battles.

That said, even in this new definition, I believe the anime does have fillers still like the nails in S01E06.

## Edit: Answer 3 - later in the manga

Wait I have another answer now. With the way the manga is going now (Chapter 250 onwards), it doesn't look like this series is some mere slice-of-life. Like it evolved from such or something.

- Wait actually Aka Akasaka talks about this exactly in Volume 22 Chapter 221.1, like right after Chapter 220 where

> Kaguya and Miyuki do it.

Anyhoo there might be some spoilers so I'll spoiler tag the afterword, but basically Aka says Volume 14 was kind of a turning point, so I guess there are less filler (in either definition?) chapters after this Volume.

Without further ado, here's the last part of the afterword.

> [image]

## Edit: Answer 4 - the movies.

Actually, as an alternative to the anime/manga, you can watch the live action movies. (They weren't quite so well-received, but me personally I really liked them.)

There are 'filler' stories in the movies but are extremely limited, mostly in the beginning of the movies and necessary to set the background of the story. They turned certain episodes/chapters that might be considered 'filler' (even in the new definition) to be relevant to the main Miyuki x Kaguya story and turned even less relevant or less immediately relevant episodes/chapters to be more relevant eg Kaguya's health issues and lack of sex education.